# Can't print the data of a user with join of 5 tables using yii

Tags: php, yii

I am a beginner in **Yii**. Now doing a jobsite. I want to print the user data with `inner join` of 5 tables. Tables are `user`, `job_seeker_profile`, `job_profile`, `location`, `category`. My controller is `sitecontroller` and my view file is `one_jobseeker.php`.

My error is

```
"Undefined index: name
C:\wamp\www\yii_new\jobsite_orginal\protected\modules\admin\views\site\one_jobseeker.php(11)"
```

var_dump shows

```
  array (size=1)
  0 => 
  array (size=22)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'jobseeker' (length=9)
  'email' => string 'jobseeker@gmail.com' (length=19)
  'password' => string 'ee33e27629d97b8da3cf77fedf1c349a669ca1ff' (length=40)
  'role' => string 'user' (length=4)
  'status' => string '1' (length=1)
  'created' => string '2014-04-11 11:48:05' (length=19)
  'modified' => string '2014-04-11 11:48:05' (length=19)
  'user_id' => string '15' (length=2)
  'contact_no' => string '342488888' (length=9)
  'gender' => string 'F' (length=1)
  'dob' => string '2014-04-08' (length=10)
  'mstatus' => string 'S' (length=1)
  'address' => string 'yyy' (length=3)
  'location_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'title' => string 'IT, Computer Science' (length=20)
  'key_skills' => string 'php,mysqls' (length=10)
  'experience' => string '2225' (length=4)
  'salary' => string '300005' (length=6)
  'resume' => string 'Blue hills585.jpg' (length=17)
  'category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'description' => string 'Information Technology, Computer Science' (length=40)
```

Controller

```
   public function actionone_jobseeker()
  {
      $id  =$_GET['id'];
     $item = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
     ->select('*')
     ->from('user u')
     ->join('job_seeker_profile s','u.id = s.user_id')
      ->join('job_profile j','u.id = j.user_id')
      ->join('location l','l.id = s.location_id')
      ->join('category c','c.id = j.category_id')
      ->where('u.id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
     ->order('u.id')
        ->queryAll();
       $this->render('one_jobseeker',array('item' =>$item));
   }
```

view-   one_jobseeker.php

```
  <div>
  <div style="float:right;margin-right:285px;">
  <h3 align="left" style="margin-left:-480px;">Jobseeker Detail</h3>
 <table  border="1" align="left" >
 <tr>
 <td>Name:</td>
 <td><?php echo $item['name'];  ?></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Anybody help me?

Comment: You use `queryAll()`, which returns *an array of DB records* instead of a single one. `var_dump` even shows you that you have *an array with a single record in it*, not *a single record*.

Comment: i want to print the data of a perticular user ,condition user_id='$id' ie  one row .

Comment: Dcoder,Can u help me please..

Answer (score 1):

As @DCoder pointed out, you are using `queryAll()` in your controller which returns an array regardless that it only contains one row.

When you use a condition that is known to return only single row, use `queryRow()` instead:

```
$item = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
 ->select('*')
 ->from('user u')
 ->join('job_seeker_profile s','u.id = s.user_id')
  ->join('job_profile j','u.id = j.user_id')
  ->join('location l','l.id = s.location_id')
  ->join('category c','c.id = j.category_id')
  ->where('u.id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
 ->order('u.id')
    ->queryRow();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo $item[0]['name'];  ?>
```

add this code into one_jobseeker.php